# slides.js causing unpredictable behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm using slides.js in a website, and the page so far is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But about 1/4 times the page loads, it instead looks like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 860,
        height: 250,
        pagination: false,
        generatePagination: false,
        navigation: {
            active: false
        },
        play: {
            active: false,
            effect: "fade",
            interval: 7000,
            auto: true,
            pauseOnHover: false
        },
        effect: {
            fade: {
                speed: 2000
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And the HTML is just the slides.js standard:

```
<style>
    #slides {
        display: none;
    }
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 860px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is unfathomable annoying. It would be nice if this problem would at least be consistent.

Comment: Looks like the standard there. but what about the rest of your html? I am curious to see if there is a missing closed tag or a lingering span somewhere.

Comment: @DanBradbury I looked through and can't find anything, buy my entire document is at http://pastebin.com/9nkGiKzk

Comment: Are you using the new SlidesJS, or the legacy version?

Comment: @JulesMazur 3.0.3, the newest I believe.

Comment: Also, I just refreshed, and got a third type of screwup: http://i.imgur.com/hHynSzk.png